# codeigniter - Two Controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I made a simple login system, with help of codeigniter. I have created a user section where user can see concern data(coming from DB) after login.

I made another controller and module for this but now I am confused How to use two controllers to manage this or if I can make only one model?

so how can I call this model on my home page where user gets redirected after login, please suggest your ideas on this confusion.

for login system i have these files

> 1. Controller 
>     (a) login.php 
>     (b) home.php 
>     (c) verfiylogin.php
> 2. Models
>     (a) user.php
> 3. Views 
>     (a) home_view.php 
>     (b) login_view.php

For member section

> 1. Controller 
>     (a) newsletter.php
> 2. Models
>     (a) newsletter_model.php
> 3. Views 
>     (a) home_view.php 
>      same home_view.php call via php

Comment: I think your controller should handle everything related to the login process, eg. auth controller that: shows login page, verify login. It doesn't sound like you should be using two different controllers.

Comment: I agree with you but i told earlier i am new in codeigniter just 5 days i use this framework so dont know the exact way to control everything that's why i ask help and clear my concept.

Thankyou so much for your precious time help & support to clear the concept.

Answer (score 1):

why do you make 2 controllers for this? login controller and verfiylogin?

in my opinion the best way to do it is to look at ion auth for codeingiter,create a model and fetch your members list after login in the user or the admin.

PS: LOL Your method is confusing....:))

Comment: very thankful to guide me on this concept, i try to learn as much i can.